# store datatable into viewstate in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, datatable, ado.net, viewstate

I've created a `DataTable _dt` and added columns like below

```
_dt.Columns.Add("INDATE", typeof(string));
_dt.Columns.Add("INTIME", typeof(string));
_dt.Columns.Add("OUTTIME", typeof(string));
_dt.Columns.Add("OUTDATE", typeof(string));
```

and I stored `_dt` into `Viewstate`:

```
ViewState["_table"] = _dt;
```

and then I added a row into that `DataTable` like this:

```
DataRow _dr = _dt.NewRow();
_dr[0] = string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", System.DateTime.Now);
_dr[3] = string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", System.DateTime.Now);
_dt.Rows.Add(_dr);
```

and bound the `DataTable` to a gridview successfully.

My problem is: whenever I retrieve the `DataTable` from `Viewstate`

```
DataTable _dtTemp = (DataTable)ViewState["_table"];
```

the table contains `DataRow` also...

I don't want the dataRow.. I want table with column field only.

Comment: Please use the appropriate button `{}` to format your code lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataTable object instance stored in the ViewState is the same object instance that you use when adding rows. So, whatever you do with it will be seen when you retrieve it the next time

You could use the [Clone method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone(v=vs.110).aspx) on your original datatable stored in the ViewState and add rows to this clone. In this way you will have two distinct objects and adding rows to the second doesn't affect the first

```
ViewState["_table"] = _dt;
DataTable temp = _dt.Clone();
DataRow _dr = temp.NewRow();
_dr[0] = string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", System.DateTime.Now);
_dr[3] = string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", System.DateTime.Now);
temp.Rows.Add(_dr);

....

DataTable temp = (ViewState["_table"] as DataTable).Clone();
....
```